# React local state does not update after onclick

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, state

I have a collection of data. I've mapped the data and passed it to my child component. I pass the items from my child component to my custom checklist. When I click each item, I can select and deselect it.

I'd like to select all of the items. I did this by adding one button to my parent component. When the user clicks the "Select All" button. It will take all data identifiers and pass them to the local state. It works, but I don't think it's the best solution. Because In my checkbox, I'm passing the boolean value of the selected item to the checkbox's component local state. When I press the all-in-one button. This local state does not change. It displays a false value by default.

**I reproduce code in [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-wave-3kb9w?file=/src/App.tsx)**

**This is my parent component**

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Multipicking from "./MultiPicking";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const Data = [
    {
      id: "FF",
      level: 2,
      name: "rice"
    },
    {
      id: "AA",
      level: 2,
      name: "juice"
    },
    {
      id: "GAA",
      level: 2,
      name: "ball"
    },
    {
      id: "FF3AA",
      level: 2,
      name: "TV"
    },
    {
      id: "FH",
      level: 2,
      name: "Pencil"
    },
    {
      id: "FHAA",
      level: 2,
      name: "Tea"
    }
  ];
  const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const checkAllItems = (): void => {
    const test = Data.map((item) => item.id);
    setSelectedIds(test);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={checkAllItems}>select all</button> 
      {Data.map((item, index) => (
        <Multipicking
          selectedIds={selectedIds}
          setSelectedIds={setSelectedIds}
          key={index}
          item={item}
          index={index}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**This is my child component**

```js
import React from "react";

import MultiPickingItemsCheckBox from "./MultiPickingItemsCheckBox";

interface Props {
  item?: any;
  index?: number;
  selectedIds?: string[];
  setSelectedIds?: (selectedIds: string[]) => void;
}

const MultiPickingItems: React.FC<Props> = ({
  item,
  selectedIds,
  setSelectedIds
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <MultiPickingItemsCheckBox
        name={`${item.level} ${item.name}`}
        id={item.id}
        setSelectedIds={setSelectedIds}
        selectedIds={selectedIds}
        level={item.level}
        selected={selectedIds.includes(item.id)} // selected
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default MultiPickingItems;
```

**This is the checkbox component**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Label = styled.label<{
  selected: boolean;
}>`
  display: flex;
  background: ${({ selected }): string => (selected ? "lightblue" : "gray")};
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;

  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px;

  border-left-width: 3px;
  border-left-style: solid;
`;

const Left = styled.span`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
`;

const Name = styled.span`
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
`;

const Check = styled.input.attrs({
  type: "checkbox"
})`
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
`;

const SVG = styled.svg.attrs({
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  viewBox: "0 0 100 100"
})``;

const Circle = styled.circle.attrs({
  r: 35,
  cx: 50,
  cy: 45,
  strokeWidth: 5,
  transform: "rotate(-90, 50, 50)"
})<{ checked: boolean }>`
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 282.743;
  stroke-dashoffset: ${({ checked }): number => (checked ? 0 : 282.743)};
  stroke: "red";
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
`;

const Mark = styled.path.attrs({
  d: "M25 50l15 18 24 -40",
  fill: "none",
  strokeWidth: 8
})<{ checked: boolean }>`
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  stroke-dashoffset: ${({ checked }): number => (checked ? 0 : 100)};
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke: "red";
`;

interface Props {
  name?: string;
  selectedIds?: string[];
  setSelectedIds?: (selectedItemsId: string[]) => void;
  disabled?: boolean;
  id?: string;
  isDragging?: boolean;
  level?: number;
  selected?: boolean;
}

const MultiPickingItemsCheckBox: React.FC<Props> = ({
  name,
  selectedIds,
  setSelectedIds,
  id,
  disabled,

  level,
  selected
}) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(selected);

  const handleChange = (): void => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    if (checked) {
      setSelectedIds(selectedIds.filter((selectedId) => selectedId !== id));
    } else {
      setSelectedIds([...selectedIds, id]);
    }
  };

  console.log({ checked });

  return (
    <Label level={level} disabled={disabled} selected={selected}>
      <Left>
        <Name>{name}</Name>
      </Left>
      <Check
        id={`field-${id}`}
        name={name}
        checked={checked}
        onChange={handleChange}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
      <SVG>
        <Circle checked={checked} />
        <Mark checked={checked} />
      </SVG>
    </Label>
  );
};
export default MultiPickingItemsCheckBox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a single source of truth, which should be selectedIds.

- in the checkbox component remove the local state and use selected directly
- Tip: in the checkbox component you can also remove the selectedIds props and use a mutator function in your handleChange function:

```js
const handleChange = (): void => {
    if (selected) {
      setSelectedIds(selectedIds => selectedIds.filter((selectedId) => selectedId !== id));
    } else {
      setSelectedIds(selectedIds => ([...selectedIds, id]));
    }
};
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-currying-thu5s

Comment: So, Using another state was wrong.

Comment: Can I ask you one question, When I selected all items. the I pass it to the `const [checked, setChecked] = useState(selected);`.  in the console selected is true but checked is false, could you explain me why

Comment: because the parameter provided to useState is only used to initialize your state value, it's won't be used again even if you change its value.

Comment: so when you start your app, nothing is selected, `selected` is false so `checked` is initialized with value `false`. Then you check all items, `selected` becomes true but checked has not changed.

Comment: Is the any reason the checked does not update. what happen If I use `useCallback`

Comment: the general rule to remember is having a single line of truth whenever you can to avoid sync issues